# skip or disable google maps marker that are close in radius 5 to 10 meter

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have this array as latitude and longitude marker. 
How to skip marker that are close in range about 5 to 10 meter?
getting array from text.file

```html
[{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25424783405257","longitude":"106.827406067554","image_name":"IMG_20150429_115341_2613531.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 11:54:26","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.37, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25431960585217","longitude":"106.827667078023","image_name":"IMG_20150429_115820_699264.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:00:27","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.31-35, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.2543484143375","longitude":"106.82757439518","image_name":"IMG_20150429_120117_8379184.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:01:24","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.31-35, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25422984183592","longitude":"106.827929714578","image_name":"IMG_20150429_120502_9778844.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:06:10","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.37, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25474628069748","longitude":"106.833319851496","image_name":"IMG_20150429_121045_1525027.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:13:34","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Jatiluhur No.3, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25424629718876","longitude":"106.827906626936","image_name":"IMG_20150429_122545_9863722.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:25:37","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.37, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.2542312339466","longitude":"106.829570964473","image_name":"IMG_20150429_123103_7950591.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:30:57","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.36, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25422328260916","longitude":"106.830807439673","image_name":"IMG_20150429_123231_1865120.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:32:30","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.28A, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.2541989248936","longitude":"106.831558130415","image_name":"IMG_20150429_123453_3663043.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:34:42","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.25, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25404510111961","longitude":"106.832625584677","image_name":"IMG_20150429_123904_7222461.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:39:06","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.20, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25430714705277","longitude":"106.834101063251","image_name":"IMG_20150429_124305_626938.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:42:55","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Raya No.103, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25535251958435","longitude":"106.8332994886","image_name":"IMG_20150429_124522_8616255.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:45:34","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Laboratorium No.3-4, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25584361810927","longitude":"106.8325887258","image_name":"IMG_20150429_125059_7300602.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:50:54","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Jatiluhur No.15, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25491599036074","longitude":"106.832590131487","image_name":"IMG_20150429_125502_292609.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 12:54:53","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Jatiluhur No.2, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25508057968553","longitude":"106.832552204924","image_name":"IMG_20150429_130516_1339514.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:05:10","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Jatiluhur No.2, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3913","categoryid":"393","latitude":"-6.25484413612163","longitude":"106.831568364522","image_name":"IMG_20150429_130831_5809511.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:08:26","description":"Cluster Kemang3 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Duren Tiga Utara I, Pancoran, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12760, Republic of Indonesia","username":"herfan"},{"referid":"3983","categoryid":"463","latitude":"-6.20259166666667","longitude":"106.840436666667","image_name":"IMG_20150429_132648_7141021.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:28:18","description":"Cluster Menteng1 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Ki Mangun Sarkoro No.46, Menteng, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10310, Republic of Indonesia","username":"Eddy JTIM"},{"referid":"3983","categoryid":"463","latitude":"-6.20324166666667","longitude":"106.84073","image_name":"IMG_20150429_133126_3254505.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:34:39","description":"Cluster Menteng1 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Sukabumi No.6-8, Menteng, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10310, Republic of Indonesia","username":"Eddy JTIM"},{"referid":"3983","categoryid":"463","latitude":"-6.20258","longitude":"106.841428333333","image_name":"IMG_20150429_133907_1501770.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:40:51","description":"Cluster Menteng1 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Ki Mangun Sarkoro No.79, Menteng, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10310, Republic of Indonesia","username":"Eddy JTIM"},{"referid":"3983","categoryid":"463","latitude":"-6.20364333333333","longitude":"106.841205","image_name":"IMG_20150429_134246_3636588.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:44:02","description":"Cluster Menteng1 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Sukabumi No.11, Menteng, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10310, Republic of Indonesia","username":"Eddy JTIM"},{"referid":"3983","categoryid":"463","latitude":"-6.20402833333333","longitude":"106.84157","image_name":"IMG_20150429_134625_2710502.jpg","upload_date":"2015-04-29 13:52:28","description":"Cluster Menteng1 - Segment1","address":"Jalan Sukabumi No.17, Menteng, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10310, Republic of Indonesia","username":"Eddy JTIM"}]
```

and here is my php files

```html
<?php
$connected = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80);
if (!$connected) {
  echo "<script>alert('need internet connection');</script>";
}
else {
  $getmarker = file_get_contents('json.txt');
  $jsonmarker = json_decode($getmarker);

  $arraylat = array();
  for ($a=0; $a < count($jsonmarker); $a++) {
    $stdlat = substr($jsonmarker[$a]->latitude, 0, (strpos($jsonmarker[$a]->latitude, '.', 1) + 8));
    $stdlon = substr($jsonmarker[$a]->longitude, 0, (strpos($jsonmarker[$a]->longitude, '.', 1) + 8));
    switch (strlen($stdlat)) {
      case 10:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat);
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon);
        break;
      case 9:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'0');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'0');
        break;
      case 8:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'00');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'00');
        break;
      case 7:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'000');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'000');
        break;
      case 6:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'0000');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'0000');
        break;
      case 5:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'00000');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'00000');
        break;
      case 4:
        $fixlat = floatval($stdlat.'000000');
        $fixlon = floatval($stdlon.'000000');
        break;  
    }
    array_push($arraylat, $fixlat.', '.$fixlon);
    
  }
  $slice = array_slice($jsonmarker, 0, 20);
  $markers = "";
  for ($i=0; $i < count($jsonmarker); $i++) { 
    $markers .= "[".$jsonmarker[$i]->referid.", ".$jsonmarker[$i]->categoryid.", ".$jsonmarker[$i]->latitude.", ".$jsonmarker[$i]->longitude."
    , , '".date("d M Y H:i:s", strtotime($jsonmarker[$i]->upload_date))."', '".$jsonmarker[$i]->description."'
    , '".$jsonmarker[$i]->address."', '".$jsonmarker[$i]->username."'], ";
    $centermap = $jsonmarker[$i]->latitude.", ".$jsonmarker[$i]->longitude;
  }
  $cleanmarkers = rtrim($markers, ', ');
  
  $arrlatdif = array();
  $moveingno = array();
  foreach ($arraylat as $key => $value) {
    array_push($moveingno, $key);
    foreach ($arraylat as $k => $v) {
      $dif = (-1 * $value) - (-1 * $v);
      if ($value != $v && $value != in_array($k, $moveingno) && $dif < 0.0001 && $dif > -0.0001) {
        array_push($arrlatdif, 'index '.$key.' similiar to index '.$k.' on latitude '.$v);
      }
    }
  }
  echo "this loop for reduce similiar value<br><pre>",print_r($arrlatdif),"</pre>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MoraMaps</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- fancybox on arhgreat -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      // this where maps called
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $centermap ?>),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(map, markers);
      }

      var markers = [<?php echo $cleanmarkers ?>];
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          var markers = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][4],
            fancyimg: locations[i][4],
            icon: './images/jb.png',
            content: '<b>latitude :</b>'+locations[i][2]+
              '<b style=padding-left:10px;>longitude :</b>'+locations[i][3]+
              '</br><b>upload date :</b>'+locations[i][5]+
              '<b style=padding-left:20px;>by :</b>'+locations[i][8]+
              '</br><b>description :</b>'+locations[i][6]+
              '</br><b>address :</b>'+locations[i][7]+'</br>'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              $.fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                iframe:{'scrolling':'no'},
                autoscale: 'true',
                //href: this.fancyimg,
                overlayShow: true,
                centerOnScroll: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 600,
                title: this.content,
                helpers : { title : { type : 'inside' }}
              });
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height: 850px"></div>
    <div id="dialog"></div>
  <style type="text/css">
    .search {
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 2px;
      float: left;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 20px 0px 0px 80px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 500px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    #searchsite {
      padding: 0px 11px 0px 13px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 32px;
      outline: medium none;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    #searchresult {
      position: fixed; 
      z-index: 100;
    }

    #panel {
      position: fixed;
      top: 20px;
      left: 80%;
      margin-left: -180px;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 60%;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    #panel3 {
      position: fixed;
      top: 55px;
      left: 80%;
      margin-left: -180px;
      z-index: 5;
      font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 75%;
      height: 20px;
    }

    #panel3 img {
      height: 18px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    #dialog {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

still working on for loop 
I think the close range is in south jakarta area
marker shown here is still from the array(from text files)
notes on abbove is my progress doing

Comment: you need to show us some code, what you have tried etc.

Comment: oke... just turn off my pc, and its getting on again...BTW why I'm vote down?

Comment: 5 to 10 meter range from what/where?  What markers?

Comment: @geocodezip : from each marker my friend, I'm still doing for loop, maybe you can copy the code to your server for trial

Comment: asking this question make me get vote down, its hard to get reputaion here... :( and people just vote down and leave

Comment: @cmorrissey I have add my code

Comment: @cmorrissey  I have add my answer, maybe you can vote up

Comment: @geocodezip  I have add my answer, maybe you can vote up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause no one trying to answer and just vote down to this question
so I do some little trick for this in my `.php` files

```html
<!-- read json -->
<?php
$getjsonstring = file_get_contents('json.txt');
$arrayforcheck = array(); // hold value for check with in_array
$arraytouse = array(); // result array will be here
$arrayredundant = array(); // all redudant store here
$arraysimiliar = array(); // range less than 10m store here

// here is the loop
for ($a=0; $a < count($arrjson); $a++) {
$lat = $arrjson[$a]->latitude;
$lon = $arrjson[$a]->longitude;
$referid = $arrjson[$a]->referid;
$categoryid = $arrjson[$a]->categoryid;
$imagename = $imageurl.$arrjson[$a]->image_name;
$upload_date = date("d M Y H:i:s", strtotime($arrjson[$a]->upload_date));
$description = $arrjson[$a]->description;
$address = $arrjson[$a]->address;
$username = $arrjson[$a]->username;

// give condition push to redundant on identic
if (in_array($lat.'|'.$lon, $arrayforcheck)) {
$arrayredundant[$a] = array($referid, $categoryid, $lat, $lon, array($imagename), $upload_date, $description, $address, $username, $message);
}
// loop for check with $arrayforcheck
else {
$passvalue[$a] = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayforcheck); $i++) { 
$splitforcheck = explode('|', $arrayforcheck[$i]);
$latcheck = $splitforcheck[0];
$loncheck = $splitforcheck[1];
$diflat = abs(round((abs($lat) - abs($latcheck)), 5));
$diflon = abs(round((abs($lon) - abs($loncheck)), 5));
if ($diflat > 0.0001 || $diflon > 0.0001) {
array_push($passvalue[$a], $diflat.'|'.$diflon);
}
// if all check with $arraycheck is pass
if (count($passvalue[$a]) == count($arrayforcheck)) {
$arraytouse[$a] = array($referid, $categoryid, $lat, $lon, array($imagename), $upload_date, $description, $address, $username, $message);
array_push($arrayforcheck, $lat.'|'.$lon);
}
else {
$arraysimiliar[$a] = array($referid, $categoryid, $lat, $lon, array($imagename), $upload_date, $description, $address, $username, $message);
array_push($arrayforcheck, $lat.'|'.$lon);
}
}
}
```

now your marker is store in `$arraytouse`
just fetch as any output form as you wanted...
hopes this help others